# Use different style for same item for different activity in android studio (Please read description)

Tags: android, android-studio, themes, android-bottomsheetdialog, background-drawable

I am working on a project wherein I want to use `BottomSheetDialog` in different activities. But for different activities I want the Dialog to have diffrent background drawable. I have set the background drawable in `themes.xml` but that makes the drawable to be applicable for `BottomSheetDialog` for the entire app, i.e, it gets applied successfully but it is constant for all activities. What I want is for diffrent activites it must have different background drawable.

This is what my `themes.xml` looks like:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <style>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
         ...
         ...
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
        parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle"
        parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/top_rounded_corners</item>  <!-- I want to change the backgroundDrawable here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Is there a way I can change drawable depending on the activity I am on. I thought of using `AndroidManifest.xml` but I am not sure how can I achieve this.
Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Hi, I think you should search about create BottomSheetDialog programmatically. As this approach, you can set style for dialog when you create.
e.g : `BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(YourActivity.this, R.style. AppModalStyle);  `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative way to solve my problem: I created another instance of themes in `themes.xml` and then change the drawable asset in this instance (see the code below).

```
<style name="Theme.Blogaro" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>

    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Blogaro.splash" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme.splash</item>  ---> Made changes here

    </style>

    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
        parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme.splash"
        parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle2</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle"
        parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/top_rounded_corners</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle2"
        parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/top_rounded_corners_splash</item>
    </style>
```

Then I programmatically change the default theme inside the `onCreate` in my `Activity.java`:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Blogaro_splash);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
```